# mod_rewrite Friendly URL clashing with 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I've been struggling with my mod_rewrite for a while now and I thought I'd cracked it…

My CMS generates blog post URLs with post.php?s= and I've been trying to remove this part of the URL so that they're nice and user friendly. Here's my mod_rewrite:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

ErrorDocument 404 http://tempertemper.net/error.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tempertemper\.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !cron.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tempertemper.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=(.+)$
RewriteRule post.php /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^resources /archive? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !post.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ post.php?s=$1

</ifModule>
```

Unfortunately, It seems to be directing all pages that aren't found to the blank post.php page instead of the error.php page.

My site is here: http://tempertemper.net and here's a URL that doesn't exist http://tempertemper.net/this-url-does-not-exist

It should take you to http://tempertemper.net/error

Thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: What's an example of a page that's not found? `/post.php?s=blahblah`?

Comment: Hi @Jon, The CMS generates example.com/post.php?s=blahblah and I'm rewriting it to example.com/blahblah

Comment: But how does it know if `blahblah` isn't found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are redirecting all paths which fit the `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` pattern, this will simply send to your post.php script the query string `s=this-url-does-not-exist`. So it's up to your PHP script post.php to check whether `this-is-not-a-url` exists or not, as Apache cannot possibly know what blog post ID values are valid and which are not.

As a side note, I'd recommend using `/blog/2012-08-24-whatever` as the path you give to visitors, rather than `/2012-08-24-whatever`. That way you can reserve paths for other functions, such as `/images` without having to write a new exception in your .htaccess file every time you need to create a new utility path.

Comment: I've moved the blog into its own folder now, as recommended. Thanks. So everything that's not an existing page is being redirected? I guess moving the blog to its own folder with its own .htaccess allows the 404 to work across the rest of the site. But I guess it would be best to rewrite the mod_rewrite for the blog somehow. I'm a bit lost… How would you remove the post.php?s= from the URL? What I'm after is a way of all blog posts that generate redirecting from example.com/blog/post.php?s=nice-post to example.com/blog/nice-post. Thanks for your help @user1515834 :)

Comment: And that's what you appear to have. But because a user can provide a /blog/name-of-post which fits the pattern perfectly, but refers to an article which does not exist, you need to modify your PHP script to check whether name-of-post actually exists and, if it does not, tell the PHP script to issue a 404 header and a message explaining to the user that they have requested an article which does not exist. Apache cannot know which blog articles exist if they are being fetched by PHP from a database.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry if I've been a bit slow on the uptake– mod_rewrites are not my forte! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Bit off topic, but I don't suppose you know how to escape a ? character in a url, do you? This won't work because of the ? but I need to direct the original URL to the new one:
RewriteRule ^post.php?s=2012-04-28-evernote$ /blog/evernote? [R=301,L]

Comment: To avoid making a mess here, it's probably best if you start a new question for that. Make sure to tag it with .htaccess mod-rewrite and php to get attention from the right people.

Comment: Cool. Thanks again for your help and maybe see you on the new question!